# Rails capybaraAmbiguous match, found 50 elements matching css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

I get this error:

```
Ambiguous match, found 50 elements matching css "input[value=\"delete\"]"
```

When I put the following code:

```
find('input[value="delete"]').first.click
```

On html file:

```
<div id="deletediv-38">
    <form class="button_to" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" method="post" action="/del/38">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
        <input type="submit" name="delete-38" value="delete" />
    </form>
</div>

<div id="deletediv-39">
    <form class="button_to" onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" method="post" action="/del/39">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
        <input type="submit" name="delete-39" value="delete" />
    </form>
</div>
.
.
.
```

`find('input[id="delete-38"]')` doesn't work , it says element not found.

And I can't count as well.
when I do

```
find('input[value="delete"]').count.should_be > 0
```

I again get the error:

```
Ambiguous match, found 50 elements matching css "input[value=\"delete\"]"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [this](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FFinders%3Afirst) instead:

```
first('input[value="delete"]').click
```

Answer (score 3):

To explain the errors you're having -

[find](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#find-instance_method) will find one unique element, if there are none or more than one matching you will get an error.   Your find('input[id="delete-38"]')  fails because according to the html the only elements with ids are divs and have divs of the format deletediv-xx.   If you were trying to find the inputs with the name of delete-38 you would do

```
find('input[name="delete-38"]')
```

As @dimakura stated to get the first element you use [#first](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#first-instance_method).  If you want a count of the elements you need to use [#all](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders#all-instance_method) - like so

```
all('input[value="delete"]').count
```

If the page is dynamically changing and you want to know the count on the page once at least one has appeared then you could do

```
all('input[value=delete]', minimum: 1).count
```

which would use Capybaras waiting behavior for at least one to appear before returning (or it times out while waiting)

Comment: minimum work perfect the problem with first is first not wait for elements to appear and also all not wait until you give it this attribute